# Formatting Field width in UNIX

Tags: unix

I am having data in below format:

[image: Having]

[image: Require]

---

My main issue is, I have a file whose data in fields/columns are too lengthy.

If I simply show output(by command filename.xls|awk -F"|" '{print $1,$2,$3)),then it is not good to see...and very complex to read.
as:
*fghfhgjhhhkkkkkkkkkkkkkjggihkjlkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkmnkbjguyuyu yyuyguggugyrdgvjbkjnkl fuyffffhgghfhfhfddtdxgxgfugjb uguyffhhigguyt7gbjtujbkb..............*

....is it possible to set the FIELD WIDTH???

Thanks

Update...to **ghoti** and **tripleee**(Please zoom if not clear)
Input file is tab delimeted......

[image]

Comment: Is your input tab delimited? Do you want the output to be tab delimited, with padding at the top when folding doesn't fill all lines? Your examples look like Excel, not text files.

Answer (score 2):

Use awk's substr() function.  eg: 
    **awk '{print substr($3,0,10)}'**

**man awk** for details.

Answer (score 2):

From a shell, you can use the "fmt" command to wrap text at a number of columns:

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ text="dfgkjfd vonhsadoi djo asdoi sdojvdjkdo soij dsmioo broingli."
[ghoti@pc ~]$ printf '%30s\n' | tr \  -
------------------------------
[ghoti@pc ~]$ fmt -30 <<<"$text"
dfgkjfd vonhsadoi djo asdoi
sdojvdjkdo soij dsmioo
broingli.
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```

You should `man fmt` to verify the command line options in your environment.  The `<<<Text` notation is use by the `bash` shell, and isn't necessarily how you want to use this command.

Layout within a table is more complex, and can't be done simply by awk alone.

Comment: So for the whole task, in Bash, something like `while IFS=$'\t' read a b; do paste <(fmt -w 36 <<<"$a") <(fmt -w 36 <<<"$b"); done <filename.xls` assuming it is indeed a text file with tab delimiters. This does not attempt to align to the bottom of each logical line, which is against nature anyway.

Comment: Hi triplee....Thanks for the post.
I am facing another problem with this...Is there any way to start the 2nd,3rd....column values at a fixed position....

My output is coming like this..

aaaaaaaa        bbbbbbbbbcc
vvvvvvvv        nknkkkkkk
            khkkkkk jbjgj

Comment: Example...
If I have 2 columns, column1 has 1 row of value...column2 has 3 rows of values....when output is coming 1st row is OK with 1 tab separated.
For 2nd,3rd row o/p is coming with one tab back....since there is no value in Column1...The alignment of 2nd,3rd column is not OK.

Is there any way to make the alignment...?
thanks

Comment: @pkawar - I'm not understanding your data format from your explanation.  Could you provide more detail, like a properly formatted sample [as an update to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12025929/edit)?